# Docker with Azuracast and ffmpeg on 1 VPS with reverse proxy conflict port 443

Tags: docker, nginx, ffmpeg

I use Azuracast via Docker and FFmpeg on 1 VPS running with reverse proxy on NGINX.
Azurecast is configured to use a certificate (Letsencrypt).
ffmpeg is also using an Letsencrypt certificate.
Both are different certificates.

Azuracast runs on audio.domainname.com,
FFmpeg runs on video.domainname.com

Both on the same IP (same VPS).

Separately both tools are functioning fine, but it is impossible to start them together because of a port 443 which is in use by one of these tools.

Letsencrypt doesn't allow to change the port 443 in one of the tools.

What can I do to let both tools run at the same time on the same VPS?